# How can I get this Script to run multiple Words

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyo,

I'm currently stuck with a script. I want to delete a specific word in a HTML tag that I can't change the markup for. I searched for a solution and found this script:

```
$(':contains("bad")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("bad").join(""));
});
```

Now this script works fine for one word (`bad`) but I want to remove `mutliple` words with this script. So I tryed this:

```
$(':contains("bad", "good")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("bad","good").join(""));
});
```

But this doesn't work at all.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
$(':contains("bad")').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().split("bad").join(""));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>A beautiful badsentence</div>
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `.replace(/bad|good/g, '')`. Here `/g` means replace all matches, not just first one. `bad|good` means replace any of these.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#text').text($('#text').text().replace(/good|bad/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="text">Some words are not as good or not as bad, but bad words may be good too.</span>
```

Comment: And how do I make this work when the words 'good' and 'bad' are written like [good] and [bad]?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 var replaced = $('#text').text().replace("good", '').replace("bad", '');
 $('#text').text(replaced);
```